# PyQt4 and GUI for Raspberry Pi 3 - Python

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, raspberry-pi, qtcore

I am creating a GUI in Qt Designer 4.8.6 to control the pins of my Raspberry Pi 3. I could already read and write on pins through the Qt, the problem is I can only do this when I press any button (or when any other standard signal from Qt is generated). I know that I need a thread running in parallel to generate a signal for communicate with a SLOT inside the class MyWindow. The code below already running the GUI and the Thread in parallel, now I need to know how to make this connection between the two classes, because I can not use the elements of MyWindow class within the thread. How I wish display the status of the inputs in "real time" in the GUI, I need this reading is done within the MyWindow class through a function that will be executed after a signal generated by Thread. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you very much!

```
import sys     
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time      
import re
from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication



GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) # Specifies referring to GPIO pins by Broadcom SOC     channel
GPIO.setwarnings(False) #Disables the Warning



status = "nil" # variable initialization
s = 0          # variable initialization 

class Main(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.doSomething()

    def doSomething(self):
        print ("Doing Something")

class MyWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow): #Class to bind ledonoff.ui with Python             Script do not change anything here
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('ledonoff.ui', self)
        self.show()

        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.high,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),    self.GPIO4On) # Function to be fired on Button Click Action
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.low,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.GPIO4Off)  # Function to be fired on Button Click Action

  def GPIO4On(self):  # Function declaration which fires on respective button click
        GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT)  #Set GPIO Pin as Output 
        s = GPIO.output(4, 1) # Turns the GPIO logical High
        self.output.setText("GPIO4 has been turned ON in OUTPUT Mode") #Append the current GPIO pin status
        GPIO.setup(19, GPIO.IN)
        s = GPIO.input(19)

    def GPIO4Off(self): # Function declaration which fires on respective button click
        GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT) #Set GPIO Pin as Output 
        GPIO.output(4, 0) # Turns the GPIO logical Low
        self.output.setText("GPIO4 has been turned OFF in OUTPUT Mode")

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
   window = MyWindow()
   mainThread = Main() # build the thread object (it won't be running yet)
   mainThread.start()  # run will be executed in a separate thread
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Why can the thread not interact with the window? If you have an instance of the window in the thread, you can call any function you want

Comment: Good afternoon! I read the inputs in the thread, however I could not show the status in the graphical interface, because when I use the label whitin the Main class, he is not declared. So I need "wake up" a function inside the MyWindow class so I can read the inputs and write their status in the label.

Comment: As far as I understand your question, you would need inter-thread communication. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789344/implementation-of-inter-thread-communication-in-qt

Comment: How can I implement this?

Comment: You may want to look at this example: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/pyqt/2775/using-threads-with-pyqt/9346/the-worker-model#t=201607310009395147542

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but there is already a thread in the program. I need to know how to generate a signal from the thread in parallel to perform a function within the MyWindow class, or in another case, how to use instances of MyWindow class within the thread (main class). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the tips! Resolved in a simpler way ... I was able to write in instances of MyWindow class within the thread!